# How to insert tab character in "dialog"?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm using the linux "dialog" utility to create a simple UI.
However, there is a text in infobox and I want to insert tab characters in order to properly align the text.

But it seems, that dialog does not accept tab character. Also, the --tab-correct option did not help. If I write \t, it apperas at \t in the infobox.

```
dialog --title "Hello" --tab-correct --infobox "tab \t test" 20 100
```

If I insert a tab in the command string:

```
dialog --title "Hello" --tab-correct --infobox "tab         test" 20 100
```

it appears as a single space.

Is there a way to insert tab in the infobox text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `--no-collapse` option, instead of `--tab-correct`, and insert literal tabs in your string, for example with

```
"star "$'\t'" end"
```

or using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> and pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Comment: Thank you very much! This --no-collapse option solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know dialog, but sometimes in Linux when \t doesn't interpreted as Tab, try

> "`echo -e "\t"`"

Try this:

```
declare -r TAB="`echo -e "\t"`"
echo -e "A${TAB}B"
```

Answer (score 1):

The command string you say that appears as a single space is appearing as 8 spaces here, not a tab (but maybe that's StackExchange).

Debugging this may be a bit tricky. There are several things that may or may not "cook" tabs: the terminal, when inserting the character; the shell, when processing the input; the underlying terminal mode (cooked mode vs. raw mode), and, in the end, dialog itself.

To make things even more confusing, if you use echo to generate a tab, or if you somehow else generate a tab, there's still a chance the terminal emulator decides to wash that off.

A commonly seen keystroke to escape this kind of control characters is `C-v` (that is, `Control+V`, `CTRL+V`). If you hit that, then tab, you may get a real tab inserted. Here with the GNU `bash` and `urxvt`, it works.

Properly debugging this requires knowing *exactly* what's the issue (that is, what's eating the tab). Simply putting \t there won't work unless either `dialog` or your shell have the feature to translate these escaped sequences. If you want those, then follow @Eran Ben-Natan's advice and use GNU `echo`'s enhanced mode (other implementations may/will differ — there's no specific behavior specified in POSIX (IEEE 1003.1 2008, page 2615, line 84306)).